# Derivatives and Integrals are both what of a function?

Tags: calculus, terminology

This is more a question on semantics.  I'm writing a document and would like to describe a collection of functions that are both derivative and integral representations of a specific function.  Is there any term or phrase to describe this group?

Comment: Small note, 'group' means something special in mathematics so you are better off calling this a collection or set of functions.

Comment: Understood, changed above.

Comment: Can you provide a little more context/an example sentence, and your goal/audience?

Comment: Sure.  Mainly I'm discussing the topic internally in my company so the audience isn't that formal.  I have feedback from an actuator that is both position and velocity, and am using cascading PID control so I happen to have both the process variable and the derivative for my position loop and the process variable and my integral for the velocity loop.  The semantics gets a little fuzzy so I was just trying to say that I was taking advantage of the mulit-(insert word or phrase here) feedback to satisfy inputs to my PID's.  I thought there would be a quick answer and it sound as if there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a precise term that is not too common, various derivatives (first, second, etc.) and anti-derivatives could all be called "[**differintegrals**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral)" of the original function.

Depending on whether it is obvious to your audience from the context that anti-derivatives are to be included (they're almost like differentiating a negative number of times), I'd probably just accept the imprecision and use "**derivatives**" in your situation.

I can't think of anything else short for this, even the vague "results after applying operators" is too long.

Comment: This is the response I was looking for, thank you.  "Differintegrals" was the word I was looking for, however, it sound a little awkward and I think using "derivatives" in the generic sense to include anti-derivatives will handle the situation better.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Upto a constant the integral and differential coefficients of $ c e ^{\pm x} $ form the same set of functions.

Second differential order invariant function..

Comment: OP is asking about the name for such a set of functions, not a particular example.